# "За Плутоном нашли еще одну планету." "Еще одну" - как понимать?

Tags: семантика

> "За Плутоном нашли еще одну планету".

"Еще одну" - это по отношению ко всем планетам Солнечной системы или по отношению к планетам, расположенным за Плутоном? Возможна ли здесь двоякая трактовка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, двоякая трактовка возможна:
1. За Плутоном уже есть планета, а теперь нашли еще одну.
2. За Плутоном нашли планету, это еще одна планета Солнечной системы.

Но авторы полагаются на эрудицию читателя, который знает, что прежде Плутон считался последней планетой Солнечной системы.

Answer (score 1):

Между приведенными Вами вариантами трактовки нет разницы, поскольку любая планета, обнаруженная за орбитой Плутона, является в то же время и планетой Солнечной системы. Другие возможные трактовки (например: (а) учёные обнаружили экзопланету; (б) учёные вылетели за орбиту Плутона и нашли какую-то планету, находясь там и т.п.) следует исключить исходя из построения предложения и общекультурного контекста.